# How to install a python package from azure artifact feed to databricks and kubernetes

Tags: azure

I've created a test python package and uploaded it to azure artifact feed. I can install and use it on my computer with pip foloowing instructions for pip connection (install keyring, artifacts-keyring and so on).
Now I want to use the same package in an azure databricks or a docker container in kubernetes. How can I install it there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visit your "Profile" page on Azure DevOps, then generate a *personal access token*.

The token should have the "Read" permission for the "Packaging" scope (which provides access to *create, read, update, and delete feeds and packages*).

Then take the Artifacts Feed Index URL and add `<name>:<token>@` right after the `https://` part.

The *name* and *token* work analogous to a username/password combination here. The name can be anything (even an empty string).

Comment: It should have the permission for Packaging (Read). And that's enought

Comment: This answer did not work for me. Does it still work?  Can you confirm the format?  I used the following for the repository location.  (The personal access token is fake, but I put numbers that look correct.)  `https://silly:ddpa8d591b9593208265150883af567455023@pkgs.dev.azure.com/myOrg/myProj/_packaging/myFeed/pypi/simple/ myPackage` Is that correct?

Comment: @MikeWilliamson I tried just now and it works for me; I didn't use `<name>:<token>@` but just `<token>@`. If you're having problems, try generating a fresh token – perhaps the old one has expired.